# Case statement in oracle with comparision in Then clause

Tags: oracle11g, case

I am new to using Oracle trying something similar to below code, but unable to accomplish the task.

```
CASE
WHEN Dimension='abc'
then value=100
When Dimension='def'
then Value between 200 and 300
end
```

but it is throwing error `Missing Keyword state`

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: is this part of your where clause?

Comment: Yes Ramblin this is part of my where clause

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your where clause this way.

```
(Dimension='abc' and value=100)
or 
(Dimension='def' and value between 200 and 300)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ramblin but I want to write this in case statement as I am using a tool that will dynamically generate a where clause, So is there any way to accomplish the same using Case. If not possible is there any other way to accomplish the same . thanks