# Relational operator inside case clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, where-clause

I get a "missing keyword" error for the following simple code:
How can I get a result 3 , 4, and 5 if `i_check` = `'Y'` AND only 4 and 5 if `i_check` = `'N'`

```
WITH t(val) AS
     ( SELECT 1 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE CASE WHEN i_check  = 'Y' THEN VAL >= 3
           WHEN i_check  = 'N' THEN VAL  > 3
      END;
```

**Editing** with a clear data:

```
 WITH t(val) AS
     ( SELECT trunc(sysdate) FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '10' minute FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' hour FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '2' hour + interval '1' second FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + 1 FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t

19/02/2014 12:00:00 AM
19/02/2014 12:10:00 AM
19/02/2014 01:00:00 AM
19/02/2014 02:00:01 AM
20/02/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

The inputs are `i_check` and `i_date`

if `i_check = 'Y' AND i_date =`19/02/2014 01:00:00 AM'` then

```
19/02/2014 01:00:00 AM, 19/02/2014 02:00:01 AM, 20/02/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

if `i_check = 'N' AND i_date =`19/02/2014 01:00:00 AM'` then

```
19/02/2014 02:00:01 AM, 20/02/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Thanks for any help in advance:)

Comment: try this: WITH t AS
 (SELECT level as val FROM dual connect by level <= 5)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE val >= decode(&i_check, 'Y', 3, 4)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534054/case-statement-in-oracle-with-comparision-in-then-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE WHEN must return a value, not a statement. Why just not user simple logical AND/OR statements? :) For example, the first query can be rewritten like this:

```
WITH t(val) AS
     ( SELECT 1 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (i_check  = 'Y' AND VAL >= 3)
      OR (i_check  = 'N' AND VAL > 3);
```

---

As for the second query, it should be something like this:

```
WITH t(val) AS
     ( SELECT trunc(sysdate) FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '10' minute FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' hour FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + interval '2' hour + interval '1' second FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT trunc(sysdate) + 1 FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (:i_check = 'Y' AND VAL >= :i_date)
      OR (:i_check = 'N' AND VAL > :i_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a `boolean condition` to a where clause, instead use case like this way

```
 WITH t(val) AS
     ( SELECT 1 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 FROM dual
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 FROM dual
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE val > (CASE WHEN i_check  = 'Y' THEN  2
                  WHEN i_check  = 'N' THEN  3
              END);
```

Comment: Thanks for your try, But the above date is sample and I will not knowing the actual data, say for example its a date_time field.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 - what do you mean? This doesn't use any information that wasn't in your example, and would work with dates as well.

Comment: @AlexPoole and San, I've included some more data. Please have a look:)